# Find the GS to the following InHomo System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$x_1' = x_1+3x_2 + e^{-2t}$

$x_2'= x_1-x_2$

is the InHomo System.

This is using eigenvalues and eigenvectors to solve this Inhomo DE.

The book gives me the answers, I just need help understanding it.

I need help solving for the unknown vectors. I don't understand how the book got the answers below. If anyone can help me with this I would really appreciate it. I don't understand how they got $E=-\cfrac{1}{4}\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0  
\end{pmatrix}$

$G=\cfrac{1}{4}\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
-1  
\end{pmatrix}$

The book completely skips this part and I would like help understanding how they got those vectors.

Thank You For Any Help.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to solve the given equations ?
$$-2G=AG$$
$$(A+2I)G=0$$
$$\left(\pmatrix {1 & 3 \\ 1&-1}+ \pmatrix {2&0 \\0&2} \right)G=0$$
$$\pmatrix {3 & 3 \\ 1&1} \pmatrix {g_1 \\g_2}=0$$
$$\implies g_1=-g_2$$
$$\implies G=k\pmatrix {1 \\-1}$$
Plug this in the first equation:
$$-2E+G=AE+ \pmatrix {1 \\0}$$
$$(A+2I)E=G- \pmatrix {1 \\0}$$
$$(A+2I)E= \pmatrix {k-1 \\ -k}$$
$$\pmatrix {3 & 3 \\ 1&1} \pmatrix {e_1 \\e_2}= \pmatrix {k-1 \\ -k}$$
$$-3k=k-1 \implies k =\dfrac 14$$
$$e_1+e_2 =-\dfrac 14$$
If you choose  $e_2=0$ then $e_1=-\dfrac 14$. and $E=-\dfrac 14 \pmatrix {1 \\0}$.

Comment: Oh It's just system of equations. Thank You so much. High School Algebra continues to evade me.

Comment: So is there flexibility in the answer? Like if you choose something like $e_2=1$ so that $e_1=-\cfrac{5}{4}$ would that considered fine? Are these Eigenvectors? I don't think they are eigenvectors (I think they are just regular vectors so there should only be one valid answer for each) so is it just coincidental that any combination that satifies $e_1+e_2=-\cfrac{1}{4}$ is a valid solution? (If there is flexibility)

Comment: Surely you can choose another vector of course @StevenRichards In the notes they took zero because it's more simple thats all.

Comment: You're very welcomed...@StevenRichards

Comment: I see so this is just a very specific case. In other cases (like the others in this book). There can only be one specific answer for these vectors. Here in this case since $G = k(1,-1)^T$ there can be multiple answers as long as the constraint $e_1+e_2=\cfrac{-1}{4} $ is fulfilled correct? This is NOT mean that E and G are eigenvectors however. It just means that any solution to $e_1+e_2=\cfrac{-1}{4}$ will work because $G = k(-1,1)^T$ which is very unique and a special case, correct? Have I made a flaw in my reasoning somewhere?

Comment: E and G are vectors. Eigenvectors are the solution to the homogeneous differential equation...@StevenRichards

Comment: Yes $k$ is unique from the equations solved. But you can choose another value than zero for the vector E. @StevenRichards

Comment: Note that we also made some choice for the vector G. I choose as in the notes $(1,-1)$ but $(2,-2)$ will also work.

Comment: Oh sorry. I messed up the formatting in my last comment. Thank you for telling me that E and G are not eigenvectors, I just wanted to make sure of that. (Eigenvectors ONLY for homo, not Inhomo part, thank you) the answer for the inHomo part really just depends on how you WANT solve the problem overall in which using $(1,-1)$ is probably the easiest way to do so. Thank You Very Much. I think I understand a case like this clearly now.

Comment: That's great if it's more clear for you now. just reread the notes carefully. @StevenRichards